# Docker private repo with multiple images

Tags: docker

Can we host multiple images on single private repo ?

Like

1. ubuntu:12.04
2. ubuntu:14.04

So My private repo like MYREPO:ubuntu:12.04 and ubuntu:14.04

Comment: I do not understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: private repo name has to start with your private domain name, you can't even host ubuntu:14.04 as is you have to rename/tag it as something like 127.0.0.1:5000/ubuntu:v0

Comment: @user2915097 My question is this can I host multiple images on single private Docker Hub Repo

Comment: @LingxiaoXia I got your point but my question is can I host multiple images on single private Docker Hub Repo?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes.

```
# Create a container
docker run --name image1 -it busybox echo Image1
# Commit container to new image
docker commit image1 amjibaly/stuff:image1
# Push to dockerhub repo
docker push amjibaly/stuff:image1

# Create a second container
docker run --name image2 -it busybox echo Image2
# Commit container to new image
docker commit image2 amjibaly/stuff:image2
# Push to same dockerhub repo with different tag
docker push amjibaly/stuff:image2
```

Comment: I ran the commands above before pasting them here so I can't help you unless you describe the exact commands you are running and what error message you see.

Comment: Same command which you have pasted it works for 2 images but after third image it send me http 500 meta data error

Comment: I was able to add a third image with no issues, I'd recommend contacting support@docker.com to see why you're getting 500s.

Comment: OK I will try tomorrow and let you know the results

Comment: Basically, by tagging an image multiple times by running committing changes everytime.

Comment: I can confirm that it only seems to work if all you change is the TAG. If you try to push a whole new IMAGE, it will end up in a public repo. That's been my experience.